# Prove $x_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Prove $x_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ converges to $0$.

Since $2^n>\frac{n^2}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$$-\frac{2}{n}<\frac{n}{2^n}<\frac{2}{n}.$$

Since $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, by Squeeze theoreom $\frac{n}{2^n}$ converges to $0$.

Is there anything wrong this proof?

Comment: Looks mostly good to me. Although I believe you meant "$2^n > \frac{n^2}{2}$"?

Comment: @SeokbinLee I edited It was typo thank you very much

Comment: Looks good. No need for $-\frac 2n$ though. Can replace it with $0$.

Comment: Correct, but you need to prove the new claim $2^n>\dfrac{n^2}2$. You essentially displaced the problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can it be proven by using mathamatical induction?

Comment: @NeatMath Thank you

Comment: Induction is OK but for $n\ge 2$ can use binomial $2(1+1)^n \ge 2(1+n+{n \choose 2})$

Comment: @NeatMath got it thank you

Comment: By induction, why not ?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is perfectly fine just that you don't need $\frac{-2}{n}$. You can just replace that by $0$.

Here's another alternative method by using the ratio test:

$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$.

Now take the limit on both sides and thus, using the theorem of ratio test for sequences, if the limit $L$ exists and $0\leq L<1$ then $\text{lim }x_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac n{2^n}=\frac12\frac2{1\cdot2}\frac3{2\cdot2}\frac4{3\cdot2}\frac5{4\cdot2}\cdots\frac{n-1}{(n-2)2}\frac n{(n-1)2}
\\<\frac12\frac2{1\cdot2}\frac3{2\cdot2}\frac3{2\cdot2}\frac3{2\cdot2}\cdots\frac3{2\cdot2}\frac3{2\cdot2}\to0$$

---

Possibly more obvious:

$$n=1\frac21\frac32\frac43\frac54\cdots\frac{n-1}{n-2}\frac n{n-1}<1\frac21\frac32\frac32\frac32\cdots\frac32\frac32=2\left(\frac32\right)^{n-2}.$$

And of course

$$\frac n{2^n}<\frac12\left(\frac34\right)^{n-2}.$$

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: @puka: what is unclear ? Do you disagree with the first equality ? Do you disagree with the inequality ?

Comment: I got it but I have a problem. Is this a proof?

Comment: @puka: yes it is. It is squeezing with a geometric sequence.

Comment: thank you actually this is fist time that  I saw such a proof

Comment: @puka: they call it a "proof without words". I have added a variant.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems legit. However,  your problem can be easy solved using L'Hospital Rule.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n\log2}=0$

Comment: Stolz is even better.